# what is the usage of sbt-git plugin

Tags: sbt

My sbt version is 1.1.5
I read readme in git,and add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "1.0.0")` in `plugins.sbt` . 
When I use `enablePlugins(GitVersioning)`, it's red, "Cannot resolve symbol GitVersioning"
New user to sbt, cannot figure out where did I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Reload project and error will dissapear.
Every change to sbt build definition (e.g.  `build.sbt`, `plugins.sbt`) requires sbt project rebuild.

- If working directly from sbt, type `reload` or from console `sbt reload`
- If working from *IntelliJ*, then right click on sbt project and choose *Refresh sbt project* (rebuild once) or *Auto-import* (rebuild on every change).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `addSbtPlugin` line to `project/plugins.sbt` file (create it if doesn't exist). Then add `enablePlugins(GitVersioning)` to your `build.sbt` (in the root directory of your project).

Comment: I think he has already added the line.

Comment: I think it's added to the wrong place. Question says `plugins.sbt`, I'm saying it has to be in the `project/` folder.